# SQL Server - Stop an entry being made in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, constraints

I have a table called Jobs which relates to another table called clients. I need to stop a new job from being created **by other users on the DB** unless the client table has been credit checked and TOB signed.

There is another table with columns CC and TOB are stored in boolean form.

All I need is for the Jobs table to check the other table to make sure the Client cc and tob = Y before it allows a job to be created.

Any idea how? Is it constraints or triggers?

ps cant use business rules....(not allowed)

Comment: Is this MySQL or SQL Server? You have tagged both???

Comment: SQL 2008. Sorry Im new to this. I think it has to be a constraint as other users use a front end C++ applet to see the db.

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple where clause

```
insert into jobs
(field1, field2, etc)
select value1, value2, etc
where exists
(subquery to find records of credit checked and tob signed)
```

This syntax assumes you are working with sql server where you don't need a from clause.  If you are working with mysql, it would be:

```
insert into jobs
(field1, field2, etc)
select distinct value1, value2, etc
from SomeSmallTable
where exists
(subquery to find records of credit checked and tob signed)
```

Comment: cant do it like that, there is a front end applet that users have to see the DB. I think it has to be a constraint on the table.